# Run Single Test in Cucumber Groovy

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, gradle, cucumber

I wanted to run single test in cucumber/groovy following is the structure.
[image]

If I want to run single test scenario e.g. `Scenario: Change culture` as marked in the screen shot in the command line, how should I run it?

I tried following `>gradle -Dtest.single=home-page test` and few other options by giving full path and with extention(.feature), but there was no luck.

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "groovy"
apply plugin: "idea"


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
targetCompatibility = 1.6

def version = [
        'groovy'    : '1.8.6',
        'junit'     : '4.10',
        'geb'       : '0.7.2',
        'selenium'  : '2.25.0',
        'cucumber'  : '1.0.8'
]

ext.drivers = ["htmlunit", "firefox", "chrome"]

dependencies {

    groovy "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:$version.groovy"

    testCompile "junit:junit:$version.junit"
    testCompile "org.codehaus.geb:geb-junit4:$version.geb"

    testCompile "info.cukes:cucumber-groovy:$version.cucumber"
    testCompile "info.cukes:cucumber-junit:$version.cucumber"

    // Drivers
    drivers.each { driver ->
        testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-$driver-driver:$version.selenium"
    }

}
```

Comment: Not really an answer because it's not gradle specific and you've probably long forgotten the issue by now :) but this doc may help: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags

Answer (score 0):

1st step: annotate the scenario like below:

```
@culture
Scenario: Scenario Description
Given ....
When .....
Then ....
```

2nd step: use [gradle-cucumber-plugin](https://github.com/samueltbrown/gradle-cucumber-plugin)

3rd step: edit cucumber task configuration to run scenario with @culture tag

```
cucumber {
    formats = [
            'pretty', 
            'html:build/reports/cucumber',
            'junit:build/cucumber.xml' 
    ]
    tags = ['@culture', '@other_tag']
    dryRun = false
    monochrome = false
    strict = false

}
```